# Cannot connect Informatica to the Oracle DB on Docker

Tags: oracle, docker, oracle11g, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a problem with connecting (actually at the pre installing step) Informatica to the Oracle DB running on Docker.
Because of my lack of experience and also knowledge I don’t know what may be the problem.

Has anyone had similar problem to mine?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSxuv.png)

Firstly I thought this could be problem, because I did not configure tnsnames.ora on my pc, on which Informatica will be installed, but after doing that - connection from cmd was possible, but Informatica still don't get it right.

So I decided to connect via custom jdbc url

```
jdbc:informatica:oracle:TNSNamesFile=PATHPATHPATH\tnsnames.ora;TNSServerName=XE
```

and then

```
jdbc:informatica:oracle://localhost:1521;ServiceName=xe
```

But it also doesn't work.

---

**Oracle on Docker**

listener.ora Network Configuration File:

> SID_LIST_LISTENER =   (SID_LIST =
> (SID_DESC =
> (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
> (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE)
> (PROGRAM = extproc)
> )   )
>
> LISTENER =   (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
> (DESCRIPTION =
> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
> )   )

tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File:

> XE =   (DESCRIPTION =
> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
> (CONNECT_DATA =
> (SERVER = DEDICATED)
> (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
> )   )
>
> LISTENER_XE =   (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT =
> 1521))
>
> XEPDB1 =   (DESCRIPTION =
> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
> (CONNECT_DATA =
> (SERVER = DEDICATED)
> (SERVICE_NAME = XEPDB1)
> )   )
>
> EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =   (DESCRIPTION =
> (ADDRESS_LIST =
> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC_FOR_XE))
> )
> (CONNECT_DATA =
> (SID = PLSExtProc)
> (PRESENTATION = RO)
> )   )

sqlnet.ora:

> NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT, HOSTNAME)

**Main pc, where Oracle 11g is and Informatica will be installed**

tnsnames.ora

> XE =
> (DESCRIPTION =
> (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
> (CONNECT_DATA =
> (SERVER = DEDICATED)
> (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
> )
> )

sqlnet.ora

> SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS) NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=
> (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

This **works**:

```
sqlplus INFA_DOM/INFA_DOM@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=xe)))

tnsping (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE))) 10

**tnsping xe**
```

but

```
tnsping -T C:\Oracle\Win64\product\11.2.0\client_2\network\admin\tnsnames.ora xe 10
```

gives

```
Used parameter files:
C:\Oracle\Win64\product\11.2.0\client_2\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

TNS-03505: Failed to resolve name
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNS_ENTRY`? Also ensure that `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable is set to point to `tnsnames.ora`

Comment: using jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNS_ENTRY gives error "Test Connection Failed."

TNS_ADMIN is set to path "C:\Oracle\Win64\product\11.2.0\client_2\network\admin\tnsnames.ora". Also tried with "C:\Oracle\Win64\product\11.2.0\client_2\network\admin", but it also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this problem is something that keeps you up at night, a solution has been found
Informatica doesn't work with all versions of Oracle, the desktop one I guess is no longer supported in the name of the cloud solution.
Oracle on the client machine must have the right version to make it work with Informatica, but what is also important and what was the solution to the problem - the image docker version, also must be compatible (**client: 11 will not work with 21 server**)
so if your client version is 11, then download oracleinanutshell/oracle-xe-11g from docker

Answer (score 0):

This may be access issue.
Login to the machine using an user which is running informatica. Use `sqlplus` and test the connection to the Oracle DB. If you can its fine, then check if you have defined all details in tnsnames.ora and mentioned proper connection info like user pass in infa connection.

If you cant, check if you can ping the oracle DB host, if you cant pls connect to oracle DB admin to open up port or whitelist the ip etc. so informatica can connect to Oracle DB.

Comment: After login:
> tnsping xe 

Used parameter files:

Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS_LIST= (source_route=yes) (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))) (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=XE)))
OK (0 msec)

> sqlplus INFA_DOM/INFA_DOM@localhost:1521/xe
can connect; can see some sample data

So I assume that tnsnames.ora is correct.